# jquery $.get in localhost not receiving response

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I'm attempting to make a GET request using jquery to receive a page with a user determined namespace. My index page (in jade) has a text input form this script uses:

```
script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js")
script(type="text/javascript"). 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('form').submit(function(){
                    $.get('http://localhost:3000/chat/' + $('#n').val());
                });
            });
```

And the app uses a router for all '/chat' requests, so as I understand it, the request url localhost:3000/chat/namespace goes to the router which has the following code:

```
router.use(function(req, res){
    var namespace = req.originalUrl;
    res.render('../views/chat', {namespace: namespace, pageTitle: 'chatroom'});
});
```

which then renders another jade file with the user determined namespace. However, submission of the form on the index page just refreshes the index page with the address bar displaying `localhost:3000/?`. I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or if there is a deeper problem in what I'm trying to do. I've tried to $.get() other strings such as '/chat'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        $.get('http://localhost:3000/chat/' + $('#n').val());
        event.preventDefault();  //<--- prevent form from submitting, which will refresh the page before the AJAX call completes
    });
});
```

Comment: That did prevent the reset (thank you), but its still not coming back with the new page.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to redirect the main window and skip the ajax?  e.g. `location.href = "http://localhost:3000/chat/" + $("#n").val();`  Although if that is your requirement, I fail to see the need for any jquery or click handlers at all; you can do it with plain HTML.